# htaccess prevent localhost from redirecting

Tags: .htaccess

here's my .htaccess settings for adding www to all non www-urls:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

the problem is, it's also redirecting on localhost - any ideas how to prevent this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works for you.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  \.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```